# MySQL: can deadlocks occur for a query not in a transaction

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, deadlock, query-timeout, timeout

As title says. If a transaction is locking table `X`, during which another nono-transactional query tries to insert a record into `X`, do deadlocks or "lock wait timeout" issues still occur?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "non-transactional" statements; in the absence of explicit transaction control by default a transaction simply starts at the beginning of statement execution and ends when the statement completes. As a result, any query will have to wait for a conflicting lock and might encounter a lock timeout or a deadlock.